# JavaScript WebSocket character encoding issue (text)

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm sending some data to my WebSocket server which is sometimes giving me some strange characters usually caused by the last '" (could be a co-incidence that it's always the last one). Putting a space between these characters solves the problem. I'd rather get it right however than rely on my clients implementing this space (just in case there are other combos that could result in undesired data).

An example of the JSON string I am sending in my websocket connection is:

```
{
    "action": "query",
    "tag": "test",
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE param = 'test'"
}
```

The websocket server receives:

```
{
"action": "query",
"tag": "test",
"sql": "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE param = 'test'"b}
```

I've tried sending as single line data too which doesn't solve the issue. One of the clients is written in JavaScript and the other in C++, both have this same issue. Depending on what is in the single quotes I get a different result.

The code for my test JavaScript client is as follows:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3399");
socket.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log(e.data);
    document.querySelector("#response").innerHTML = e.data;
};

function sendMessage() {
    var ws_message = document.querySelector("#ws_message").value;
    socket.send(ws_message);
}
```

And the Node.js websocket server:

```
connections[connection_id].on('message', function (message) {
    if (message.type === 'utf8') { // accept only text
        try {
            var args = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data);
            handleActions(args, connection_id);
        } catch (e) {
            serverLog(connection_id, "Message not formatted correctly");
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: It changes every time I send it...

```
{
    "action": "query",
    "tag": "test",
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE param = 'fullscreen'"
R 


{
    "action": "query",
    "tag": "test",
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE param = 'fullscreen'"
5
```

EDIT 2: Even creating an array of the data on the client and using JSON.stringify causes the same issue.

Server Log:

```
[1/12/2014 13:57:39] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE param = 'fullscreen��}
[1/12/2014 13:57:39] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
[1/12/2014 13:57:44] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE param = 'fullscreen��}
[1/12/2014 13:57:44] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
[1/12/2014 13:57:46] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE param = 'fullscreen��}
[1/12/2014 13:57:46] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
[1/12/2014 13:57:47] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE param = 'fullscreen�P}
[1/12/2014 13:57:47] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
[1/12/2014 13:57:48] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE param = 'fullscreen�}
[1/12/2014 13:57:48] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
[1/12/2014 13:57:48] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE param = 'fullscreen�}
[1/12/2014 13:57:48] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
[1/12/2014 13:57:49] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE param = 'fullscreen��}
[1/12/2014 13:57:49] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
[1/12/2014 13:57:49] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE param = 'fullscreen�/}
[1/12/2014 13:57:49] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
[1/12/2014 13:57:50] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE param = 'fullscreen�S}
[1/12/2014 13:57:50] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
```

EDIT: Buffer use logs

```
81daf101eb988a238afb856884f6d33bc9e9846499e1d32dc9ec9066c9a2d3758eeb8523c7ba827087bacb23b8ddbd44a8ccd12bcbdea34ea6b882649fec986f8cebd156a3dda344cbe890738af5d13ccbbf977487f4826299fd946fcca3d37c
[2/12/2014 07:52:45] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM settings WHERE param = 'fullscreen';?}
[2/12/2014 07:52:45] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
81daf3487331886a125287211c5fd1725140862d0148d1645145922f510bd13c1642876a5f1380391f13c96a2074bf0d3065d3625377a1073e11802d07459a261442d31f3b74a10d5341923a125cd3755316953d1f5d802b01549626540ad135
[2/12/2014 07:52:57] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM settings WHERE param = 'fullscreen';?}
[2/12/2014 07:52:57] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
81da9a516309e173026aee380c67b86b4178ef341170b87d417dfb364133b825067aee734f2be9200f2ba073304cd614205dba7b434fc81e2e29e934177df33f047aba062b4cc8144379fb230264ba6c432efc240f65e932116cff3f4432b82c
[2/12/2014 07:52:58] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM settings WHERE param = 'fullscreen';?}
[2/12/2014 07:52:58] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
81da6415b90a1f37d869107cd664462f9b7b1170cb7346399b7e05729b304661dc79103795281764d5285e37ea4f2850fa5e443f994c365af42a1770cd7e0d7bde794442f14f3650997a0567d8674428992d0260d5661776cb6f017b9e314668
[2/12/2014 07:52:59] (conn: 1)  Received Message: {"action":"query","tag":"test","sql":"SELECT * FROM settings WHERE param = 'fullscreen';F}
[2/12/2014 07:52:59] (conn: 1) Message not formatted correctly
```

Comment: What websocket lib are you using on the server?

Comment: I'm using "node-sqlite3" available here [https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3)

Comment: That's a database lib.  Maybe https://github.com/einaros/ws ?

Comment: Sorry, was having a skype call at the same time about sqlite support, never a good combo! I'm using this one: [https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node)

Comment: Can you try `connections[connection_id].bufferList.on('write', function(buf) {console.log(buf.toString('hex'));});` and add the extra output to your question?

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry.  To explain myself: random characters appearing at one end of a buffer is indicative of bad buffer re-use somewhere.  That line I gave you to try will hook on some debug events in the `FastBufferList` implementation the websocket lib is using and allow me to trace the code path its taking.

Comment: Ok, I've added some logs which resulted from sending exactly the same string multiple times, not sure what I am looking for here but the text version of my strings came through different each time so it should have the information that you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help - believe it or not a simple npm update seems to have fixed it (I hope) - An update went in 3 days ago, my original install was 5 days ago.

Comment: https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/issues/170 appears to be the offending issue.  Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by an npm update command - my install of the library was 5 days old and an update went in 3 days ago which seems to have sorted it.